# xkb: `ctrl:swapcaps` option messes with the escape key

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb, xubuntu

I've been using `setxkbmap -option "ctrl:swapcaps"` to swap the capslock and left control keys, but I just recently noticed that this seems to mess up my escape key. With `xev`, I can see that pressing the escape key sends an event like:

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

After experimenting without "swapcaps" set, I was able to send the same event by pressing control and escape at the same time (`<Ctrl-Esc>`). Why should the escape key be affected by the `ctrl:swapcaps` option and how can I fix it?